# Why do butane lighters have to be filled upside down?

Tags: pressure, physical-chemistry, density, phase-diagram

Now, people say that the reason it is filled in a manner akin to this:

[image]

is because butane is heavier than air, but why should that matter if the butane escapes the canister by getting propelled out of the nozzle at high speed? shouldn't it work if a lighter is getting refilled upright too due to the by butane being expelled out if the nozzle against gravity?

Comment: Hint: what phase is butane under (very moderate) pressure?

Answer (score 1):

To properly fill an empty lighter requires that you inject *liquid* butane into the lighter reservoir. A butane refill cylinder contains liquid butane under pressure with gaseous butane in the headspace above it; to get the cylinder to feed liquid butane requires it to be held *upside-down*.

Comment: Understood, but why cant the gaseous butane be injected into the lighter reservoir? I mean if the liquid butane injected stays liquid inside the lighter, shouldn't also the gaseous butane turn into liquid inside the lighter if injected directly or, as mentioned earlier, in "upright position"?

Comment: There's no guarantee of that. IN this case, gravity is your friend.

Comment: Apologies, but can you please elaborate more on the gravity part?

Comment: gravity pulls the liquid down to the bottom of the gas container, which is where the discharge nozzle is. then when you connect the gas container to the device, the pressure inside the gas container pushes liquid into the device. this is why you have to hold the gas container upside down when refilling a device.